# Netbios support in .NET?

Tags: .net, sockets, netbios

Does MS support Netbios in .NET or not? How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik only thru PInvoke
snippet here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/NetBIOS.html

Comment: c++, please. I need on c++ lang.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.protocoltype.aspx how set netbios here?

Comment: What about a TcpListener? Can it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I had added to pinvoke.net Win 7 VB structure needed.  I've now put my entire VB 2010 NetBIOS library for Win7 at http://www.coderbliss.com/2014/10/24/windows-7-netbios-library-in-visual-basic/